# In what situation will AngularJS caching the DOM element be useful when using ngRepeat?

Tags: angularjs

I think one of the things a developer faces when using `ngRepeat`, is that the when the `i` has the same value in an array, as in `ng-repeat="i in myCtrl.arr"`, then:

```
angular.js:13236 Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. 
Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys.
```

I think it is due to AngularJS caching DOM elements by using `i` as the hash key, and so if the value can duplicate (duplicate an earlier value), we need to use

```
  ng-repeat="i in myCtrl.arr track by $index"
```

or whatever that is unique during the looping of each item.

The question is, when will such caching be useful?  Is it only when items will be rearranged, such as if the `arr` is sorted another way (in such case, will caching by `$index` automatically bust the cache? Because the `$index` being `1` in the new array is not the same as the `$index` being `1` before).  How will AngularJS know and bust the cache this way... is the `track by $index` the same as saying a hypothetical phrase `do not use cache` or `track by no cache`?

For example, if we use

```
  myRecord in myCtrl.myRecords track by myRecord.id
```

assuming `myRecord` is a database row that has the field called `id` and is unique, then AngularJS can cache the DOM elements and reuse when the DOM elements get rearranged, either when sorted in different ways or by inserting, deleting an element in the repeat? (although, I think repeating a dictionary has no definite order after a certain version of AngularJS, like beginning with AngularJS 1.3?)

Let's say if we do

```
<li ng-repeat="rec in myCtrl.authors track by rec.id">{{rec.id}} {{rec.name}}</li>
```

and in controller:

```
vm.authors = [{id: 2, name: "mike"}, {id: 3, name: "jessy"}, {id: 4, name: "mike"}];

$timeout(function() {
    vm.authors[0].id = 1;
    vm.authors.unshift({id: 2, name: "lucy"});
}, 3000);
```

I see all records updated correctly after 3 seconds.  I don't see the `lucy` record using the `mike` DOM element (and therefore showing `mike` in it).

And another thing I tried was to swap the `id` of the array elements:

```
vm.authors[0].id = 3;
vm.authors[1].id = 2;
```

And everything is updated on screen correctly.

So is caching the DOM really caching empty DOM element as an empty "shell"?  In that case, can't AngularJS just default to using `track by $index` to keep some inventory of empty shells?